# Start timer on button click HTA

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have a timer which I would like to start after a button is clicked versus using the now() variable on launch. I'm lifting the code from MSFT Script Centre. I believe the correct implementation would be to wrap the

```
pbStartTime = Now
```

line around an if argument. However, I'm not sure about the logic behind button clicked. Thanks in advance.

```
   <html>
 <title>Report Generation</title>
 <head>
 <HTA:APPLICATION 
    APPLICATIONNAME="Report Generation"  
    SCROLL="No"
    CAPTION="yes"
    MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
    MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    WINDOWSTATE="normal"
    SYSMENU="no"
    BORDER="thin"
    BORDERSTYLE="Normal"
    CONTEXTMENU="no"
    SELECTION="no">
 </head>

 <style>
 BODY
 {
 background-color: buttonface;
 Font: arial,sans-serif
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
 .button
 {
 width: 91px;
 height: 25px;
 font-family: arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: 8pt;
 }
 td
 {
 font-family: arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: 10pt;
 }                     
 #scroll
 {
 height:100%;
 overflow:auto;
 }
 SELECT.FixedWidth 
 {
 width: 17em;  /* maybe use px for pixels or pt for points here */
 }
 </style>

 <script language="vbscript">

    Dim pbTimerID
    Dim pbHTML 
    Dim pbWaitTime
    Dim pbHeight
    Dim pbWidth
    Dim pbBorder
    Dim pbUnloadedColor
    Dim pbLoadedColor
    Dim pbStartTime 

 Dim WinWidth : WinWidth = 350
 Dim WinHeight : WinHeight = 330
 Window.ResizeTo WinWidth, WinHeight

 Sub Sleep(lngDelay)
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "Timeout /T " & lngDelay & " /nobreak", 0, True
 End Sub

 Sub CheckBoxChange
    If CheckBox(0).Checked Then
    ExecuteScoreCard
    Else
    MsgBox "CheckBox is not checked"
    End If
 End Sub

 Sub ExecuteScoreCard() 

    disablebtns

    Dim sitecode
    Dim objExcel  
    Dim objWorkbook
    Dim objSheet  

    Window_OnLoad

    dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    dim path: path = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Automationsecurity = 1
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(path & "\SCORECARD.xlsm")
    Set objSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Cover Tab") 

    sitecode = document.getElementById("sitecode").value

    objSheet.Cells(4, 2) = sitecode
    objExcel.Run "SCORECARD.xlsm!Module2.RefreshConns"
    Sleep 60 

    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs path & "\Scorecards\" & "Scorecard_" & sitecode & "_" & Year(Now()) & Month(Now()) & Day(Now()) & "_" & Hour(Now()) & Minute(Now()) &".xlsm", 52
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    objExcel.Quit   

    DoAction1

    enablebtns

 End Sub

    Sub Window_OnLoad
        ' Progress Bar Settings
        pbWaitTime = 180        ' How many seconds the progress bar lasts
        pbHeight = 20       ' Progress bar height
        pbWidth= 285        ' Progress bar width
        pbUnloadedColor="white"     ' Color of unloaded area
        pbLoadedColor="black"       ' Color of loaded area
        pbBorder="grey"     ' Color of Progress bar border

        ' Don't edit these things
        pbStartTime = now()
        rProgressbar
        pbTimerID = window.setInterval("rProgressbar", 200)
    end sub

 Sub rProgressbar

    pbHTML = ""
    pbSecsPassed = DateDiff("s",pbStartTime,Now)
    pbMinsToGo =  Int((pbWaitTime - pbSecsPassed) / 60)
    pbSecsToGo = Int((pbWaitTime - pbSecsPassed) - (pbMinsToGo * 60))

    if pbSecsToGo < 10 then
        pbSecsToGo = "0" & pbSecsToGo 
    end if

    pbLoadedWidth = (pbSecsPassed / pbWaittime) * pbWidth
    pbUnloadedWidth = pbWidth - pbLoadedWidth
    pbHTML = pbHTML & "<table border=1 bordercolor=" & pbBorder & " cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=" & pbWidth & "><tr>"
    pbHTML = pbHTML & "<th width=" & pbLoadedWidth & " height=" & pbHeight & "align=left bgcolor="  & pbLoadedColor & "></th>"
    pbHTML = pbHTML & "<th width=" & pbUnloadedWidth & " height=" & pbHeight & "align=left bgcolor="  & pbUnLoadedColor & "></th>"
    pbHTML = pbHTML & "</tr></table><br>"
    pbHTML = pbHTML & "<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=" & pbWidth & "><tr>"
    pbHTML = pbHTML & "<td align=center width=" & pbWidth & "% height=" & pbHeight & ">" & pbMinsToGo & ":" & pbSecsToGo & " remaining</td>"
    pbHTML = pbHTML & "</tr></table>"
    progressbar.InnerHTML = pbHTML

    if DateDiff("s",pbStartTime,Now) >= pbWaitTime then
        StopTimer
    end if

 End Sub

 Sub disablebtns
 btnSubmit.disabled = True
 btnExit.disabled = True
 end Sub

 Sub enablebtns
 btnSubmit.disabled = False
 btnExit.disabled = False
 end Sub

 Sub StopTimer
    window.clearInterval(PBTimerID)
 End Sub

 Sub DoAction1
    MsgBox ("Successfully generated scorecard.")
 End Sub

 Sub DoAction2
    MsgBox ("Successfully generated report2.")
 End Sub

 Sub DoAction3
    MsgBox ("Successfully generated report3.")
 End Sub

 Sub ExitProgram
    window.close()
 End Sub

 </script>

 <body>
 Site Code: <input type="inputbox" name="sitecode" id="sitecode">
 <br><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox"> Scorecard
 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox"> Report2
 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox"> Report3
 <br>
 <br>
 <span id = "progressbar"></span>
 <br>
 <div align="center">
  <input type="button" name="accept" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="CheckBoxChange" style="height:30px; width:100px">
  <input type="button" name="abort" id="btnExit" value="Exit" onClick="ExitProgram" style="height:30px; width:100px">
  <br>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `Start` button, just like your `ABORT` button. Modify your `Sub Window_OnLoad` rename it to `Sub StartProcess` or something. Then in the new `Start` button that you created, add an `onClick="StartProcess"` attribute.

```
<input type="Button" value="START" name="button2" onClick="StartProcess" class="button">
```

Comment: Apologies for not including my full code, I have a submit button which calls another sub onClick. I have included my full code above.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer as it technically answers the question i asked. will post a new question